# python subprocess.Popen hanging

Tags: python, subprocess

```
            child = subprocess.Popen(command,
                         shell=True,
                         env=environment,
                         close_fds=True,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                         bufsize=1,
                                     )

            subout = ""
            with child.stdout:
                for line in iter(child.stdout.readline, b''):
                    subout += line
            logging.info(subout)
            rc = child.wait()
```

some times (intermittently) this hangs forever.
not sure if it hangs on `iter(child.stdout.readline)` or `child.wait()`

i `ps -ef` for the process it Popens and that process no longer exists

my guess is that it has do with bufsize so that child.stdout.readline is going on forever but i have no idea how to test it and as this happens intermittently

I could implement alarm but i m not sure if that's appropriate as i cant really tell whether the popen'd process is just slow or hanging

let's assume that either child.stdout.readline or wait() hangs forever, what actions could i take besides alarm ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're likely hitting the deadlock that's [explained in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

> `Popen.wait()`:
>
> Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return `returncode` attribute.
>
> **Warning:** This will deadlock when using `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use `communicate()` to avoid that.

The solution is to use [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

Comment: This is happening for me even when stdout=None and shell=False, is there any way to confirm that deadlock occurred

Answer (score 1):

Add `close_fds=True` to the call to `subprocess.Popen()` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/dropbox/pyannotate/issues/67).

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for me. The `subprocess.Popen()` still hangs when zipping around 200 ~3MB images to a single archive.