# sqlcl hangs when called using popen from airflow

Tags: python, airflow, sqlcl

We're having an issue kicking off a `subprocess.Popen` within an airflow operator.  We're using the following code to kick off sqlcl:

```
import subprocess
cmd = '/usr/local/bin/sqlcl -V'
p = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd, shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    text=True,
    executable='/bin/bash')
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    self.log.info('%s', line)
p.wait()
# we have also tried p.communicate() and p.poll() here
```

The snippet above works when run from ipython but hangs with no output when run from within airflow.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39477247/1156452 ?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith:  thank you for chiming in -- we've tried `communiate`, `poll`, and `wait` all with no luck.